# AWS EBS volume takes a long time to report as available after detachment

Tags: amazon-ec2, boto3, amazon-ebs, volumes

Sometimes when I call [detach_volume](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Instance.detach_volume) on an instance, the volume takes a long time(more than 30 seconds) to report as "available", the status of the volume is stuck in "in-use" when I can call `aws ec2 descibe-volumes`. The volume in question is never mounted. What can be the problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "The volume in question is never mounted"?
Maybe you wanted to say "unmounted"?

Are you detaching root EBS on a running EC2? The OS needs the root filesystem to function properly.

Comment: That's not a problem, that's normal operation. See boto3's `EC2.Waiter.VolumeAvailable`.

Comment: @VladSiv Yes, the volume is unmounted. I'm not detaching the root EBS.